# In bash how to copy an URL within a displayed text file without using the mouse?

Tags: bash, cat, text, url

Let me take you to this short trip:

Open terminal.

Type

`cat <any text file in your current working directory, containing a URL, at the beginning> | head`

The first 10 lines of that text file are printed on standard output, displayed on the screen.

In my case it looks like this:

`(Beginning of line 7)yada yada yada [[https://example-url-1.com][Example URL #1]] - [[https://example-url-2.com][Example URL #2]] yada yada yada (End of line 7)`

Two links, right in the middle of line 7, surrounded by text, instead of being alone in that line.

And now the quiz question: How to copy only URL #2 into memory for pasting it in another program without using the mouse?

In GNU emacs? Super easy: Search for 'ht' - cursor jumps to beginning of the link, C-M SPC, link is marked, M-w, marked section is copied. But in bash?

Comment: This may help - https://www.baeldung.com/linux/clipboard

Comment: If you're running Wayland, you should check out [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard), that replaces the `xsel` and `xclip` utilities. But the interactive part is difficult/dependent on your terminal emulator

Comment: bash is a shell a tool used to run commands. It's not a tool to select text. It can be used to run emacs. It can be used to run a command that extracts text, or another command that stores text in the X11 clipboard. It even has limited builtin support to extract text, but that's not its primary goals.

Comment: If you have the data in a file, your best bet is using some text-processing software to pick the correct line (e.g. grep and friends, most probably not Bash itself. Though how you're going to "paste it in another program" is another question). If you have a black box program that outputs the data, then pipe the output to the same tools to do the same.

Comment: But, if you have it printed on the terminal and can't re-run anything to reproduce the output, then it's something that needs to be done on your terminal, not within the shell session or through anything you can run there. (This might include mouse select with a GUI terminal emulator, or the various features of `tmux` and `screen`). Those are different situations and you need to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use GNU Emacs - it's more efficient for that
2. Isolate string - with awk, sed, grep or cut - and then use `xsel` for access to clipboard, copying the isolated string into the clipboard. No `xsel` on system? Get and install it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this when using [tmux](https://man.openbsd.org/tmux).
It has a [searchable copy mode](https://superuser.com/questions/231002/how-can-i-search-within-the-output-buffer-of-a-tmux-shell) with Emacs-like keybindings available.

You enter copy mode with `C-b` (prefix) followed by `C-[` (default keybindings), search through the output with `C-s`, go to beginning of word with `M-b`, start selection with `C-Space`, mark what you want by moving the cursor (you can also bind the `next-word` command in your config), copy selection (and exit copy mode) with `M-w`, and then paste with `C-]`.

These are the default bindings afaik, you may want to bind them differently though.
Be aware, that you may need to take extra steps to **synchronize your paste buffer with the system clipboard** if you want to paste this outside of the terminal!
But I get PTSD just thinking about my experiences with stuff like that, and it's kind of out of scope anyway.

It is a so- called terminal multiplexer, and acts as a terminal emulator within your terminal emulator.
Tmux potentially comes with its own issues (e.g. necessary time for config, an extra layer of indirection etc.).
It might or might not work for your workflow, but if you're using Emacs I assume you're willing to spend the time on configuration, and evaluating whether it works for you.
Ping me if you have questions

Comment: `tmux` (like `screen` which it is inspired from and has a similar feature) *is* a terminal emulator which can *sit* on one or more terminals or terminal emulator, not really a shell-in-a-shell, a shell being a command-line interpreter. When you run a terminal emulator (or a tmux pane), you get a shell as the default application started in it, but that doesn't mean a terminal emulator *is* a shell. I guess that's also the OP's confusion

Comment: To be precise, tmux is a [_terminal multiplexer_](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) (hence its name).

Comment: @Vilinkameni, yes, but it's also a terminal emulator like `xterm` or `gnome-terminal`. Unlike `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` it doesn't use X11 to interact with the user but a host terminal or terminal emulator, like gnome-terminals or `screen`, it supports multiple tabs, but like `screen` it has many more features including detaching from a host terminal and attaching to one (or more) others and run unattached (xterm has no builtin support to detach from a X11 server and attach to another one).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas LOL called it! I amended the wording

Answer (score 1):

Ah, but the shell's job is just to offer you a (programmable) command interface, and to execute other programs – it doesn't *do* anything with the output of these programs (unlike emacs, who takes control over how it puts e.g. the contents of files or the output of programs on the screen).

So you're kind of barking up the wrong tree there: what you want is a feature of the program that *displays* the output of the things that appear in the console, not of one of the programs that put things on the console!

So, the program you're referring to when you say "Open Terminal." is what you need to be concerned with – not the program that this starts (bash).

I don't know which terminal emulator you're using – you had no chance to tell us. So, taking a guess it might be `gnome-terminal`, which doesn't offer a way to have any keyboard interaction with the displayed console contents.

I'd recommend trying a different terminal emulator: `alacritty`. It should be easily installable on whatever Linux/BSD, MacOS or Windows you're on. It has a visual mode you might be used from the good text editor family for Unixoids; because obviously, you can't just intercept arbitrary keypresses that should be going to the programs running in the terminal, you need to change between an "interactive" and a "visual inspection mode".

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, you're dropped into a mode with <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> navigation; hit <kbd>/</kbd>, type `://`<kbd>enter</kbd> and use <kbd>n</kbd> to jump through the URLs in your terminal. Hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to open the currently highlighted link, and if you had enough, leave the mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it through...

```
perl -lne '/((http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-]))/i && print $1' | xclip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
head -n 10 filename | 
  perl -ne 'if (@M = (/\[\[(ht.*?)\]/g) and exists $M[1]) {
              print $M[1]
            }' |
  xsel -i -b
```

This will extract the second matching URL from each line and copy it to the clipboard.  If there are multiple lines containing two or more URLS then they will all be copied to the clipboard. You may want to add a newline or a tab or something to the output to separate them. You can easily add a newline to each `print` by using perl's `-l` option (i.e. use `perl -lne ...` rather than `perl -ne ...`).

If you needed only second URL from the **first** matching line, add an `exit` statement after the first successful match & print - e.g. by changing the perl code to:

```
perl -ne 'if (@M = (/\[\[(ht.*?)\]/g) and exists $M[1]) {
            print $M[1];
            exit
          }'
```

Anyway, it uses perl to capture all matching URLs into array `@M`, and then to print the second element of `@M` if it exists (perl arrays start from 0, not 1, so that's `$M[1]`).

I've used perl here because perl makes it easy to extract all substrings matching a pattern, but you could use awk or any other language (or pipeline of tools) you like.

The important tool here is `xsel`, not `head` or `perl` - xsel is what does the copying from stdin to the clipboard.  See `man xsel` for details.